# ruby - json no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, json

Playing around with ruby,

I've:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
# World weather online API url format: http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q={location}&format=json&num_of_days=1&date=today&key={api_key}

require 'net/http'
require 'json'

@api_key = 'xxx'
@location = 'city'
@url = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=#{@location}&format=json&num_of_days=1&date=today&key=#{@api_key}"
@json = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(@url))
@parse = JSON.parse(@json)
@current = @parse['data']['current_condition']

puts @current['cloudcover']
```

It returns:

`[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)` referring the very last line.

Reading answers here on SO, I see problem is that @current doesn't contain valid json. So How would I put into variable portion of the json response?

@current gives me:

```
{"cloudcover"=>"0", "humidity"=>"49", "observation_time"=>"03:18 PM", "precipMM"=>"0.1", "pressure"=>"1018", "temp_C"=>"20", "temp_F"=>"68", "visibility"=>"10", "weatherCode"=>"116", "weatherDesc"=>[{"value"=>"Partly Cloudy"}], "weatherIconUrl"=>[{"value"=>"http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png"}], "winddir16Point"=>"SE", "winddirDegree"=>"130", "windspeedKmph"=>"11", "windspeedMiles"=>"7"}
```

puts @current.inspect gives:

```
[{"cloudcover"=>"0", "humidity"=>"56", "observation_time"=>"03:39 PM", "precipMM"=>"0.1", "pressure"=>"1018", "temp_C"=>"19", "temp_F"=>"66", "visibility"=>"10", "weatherCode"=>"116", "weatherDesc"=>[{"value"=>"Partly Cloudy"}], "weatherIconUrl"=>[{"value"=>"http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png"}], "winddir16Point"=>"ESE", "winddirDegree"=>"120", "windspeedKmph"=>"11", "windspeedMiles"=>"7"}]
```

Solution:

```
puts @current[0]['cloudcover']
```

But why?

Comment: it seems `@current` is array, not hash

Comment: try `puts @current` - what do you get?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I updated OP with [@current]. Any ideas?

Comment: please show output for `@current.class`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ it says Array.

Comment: @salivan that is expectable

Comment: also update the post with `puts @current.inspect`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ done. Solution is this: puts @current[0]['cloudcover'] but I would accept explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The exception:

```
[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

says that `@current` is `Array`, not `Hash`, and since index to an array can be the only number, you get the exception. You can see it by printing the inspected value with:

```
puts @current.inspect
```

So solution is to use `[0]`, or `#first` method, in the assignment:

```
@current = @parse['data']['current_condition'].first
```